# расшифруйте код laravel webpack.mix.js

Tags: laravel, webpack

```
if (process.env.section) {
    require(`${__dirname}/webpack.${process.env.section}.mix.js`);
}
```

Что это он проверяет?

```
process.env.section
```

Это путь до корневой папки я понимаю

```
${__dirname}
```

В зависимости от найденой он подключит файл с таким именем, но где он берет эти названия? В основном env таких строк нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046696/laravel-mix-multiple-entry-points-generates-one-manifest-js

Comment: Если задана переменная окружения section, то подгружается указанный файл Mix, который ищется по имени этой переменной section